# Rails 3 - How to Increment value and update DB via link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view:

```
<h2>The current billing period is <%= @current_period %></h2>
<h2>The current period approved is <%= @approval_period %></h2>
<h2><%= link_to "Approve Period", :method => :approve, :id => @approval_period %></h2>
```

and a controller:

```
def approval_period
  @current_period = PeriodCounter.first.period.pe_number
  @approval_period = ApprovalPeriod.first.period.pe_number
end

def approve
  @approval_period = ApprovalPeriod.first.period_id
  @approval_period.update_attribute("period_id", period_id + 1)
  @approval_period.save
  redirect_to :back
  flash[:notice] = "Approval Period Updated."
end
```

I'm trying to update the database to increment @approval_period by 1 upon click of the link.  I've been away from Rails for a long time, so I know I'm missing some key elements.  Any help?  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:method` is not the method in your controller but the HTTP verb like Get or Post. Instead you should be doing something like

```
<%= link_to "Approve Period", approve_path(:period => @approval_period) %>
```

and adding approve_path in the routes.rb as

```
match "/approve" => "controller#approve", :as => :approve
```

( The above is one way of adding a route, you can [learn how to add more restful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) )

Read [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to learn more about routing.

**Update:**

```
@approval_period.update_attribute("period_id", period_id + 1)
```

The line above is what is throwing the error. You haven't defined `period_id` anywhere. The parameter that comes is at `params[:period]`.

Then, you can do this:

**Approach 1**

```
@approval_period = ApprovalPeriod.find(params[:period]) 
@approval_period.update_attribute("period_id", @approval.period_id + 1)
```

**Approach 2**

Abstract out this in a method:

```
class ApprovalPeriod < AR::Base
  def increment!
    # Here 'period_id' is valid since it is an attribute and a method 
    # with that name will be available
    update_attribute(:period_id, period_id + 1)
  end
end
```

And in the controller:

```
def approve
  @approval_period = ApprovalPeriod.find(params[:period])
  @approval_period.increment!
  ...
  # Other code here
end
```

Go with whatever suites you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think I'm closer, but I'm getting the following error upon clicking the link:  undefined local variable or method `period_id' for #<PeriodBillingsController:0xb6ca676c>

Comment: Oh, in ApprovalPeriods, there is a column period_id, which is a foreign key back to the Periods table.  Is that not a sufficient definition?  I'm sorry I'm so lame...

Comment: Then you should do @approval_period.period_id isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but where do I define @approval_period.period_id?  In the link_to or in the controller?   <%= link_to "Approve Period", approve_path(:period => @approval_period) %>  ?   or...   @approval_period = ApprovalPeriod.find(params[:period_id])
 @approval_period.update_attribute("period_id", period_id + 1)

Comment: That did it - thank you soooo much.  I'm beginning to understand this much better!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

Add this method to your `ApprovalPeriod` model.

```
class ApprovalPeriod < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  .
  .
  def increase_period
    self.increase! :period
  end
end
```

## Controller:

```
def approve
  @approval_period = ApprovalPeriod.find(params[:period_id])
  @approval_period.increase_period
  redirect_to :back
  flash[:notice] = "Approval Period Updated."
end
```

Comment: Hi Kleber, I tried that, but get this error:  Couldn't find ApprovalPeriod without an ID